# Jquery help needed - selecting a dom element right after creating it

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Why is this piece of code not working on Chrome 4.0 but works on FF 3.5. The problem that occurs is the selector $('li#node-'+nodes[i].id +'').append function is not working in chrome but is working fine in firefox. Is there a problem with appending to DOM elements that have been created on runtime in Chrome? Should I use Jquery.live() ?

```
   $.getJSON("/data/all" , function(data){
                    nodes = data;
                    len = nodes.length;
    for(i=0; i<len; i++){
                        if(i==0){
                           // works on FF && Chrome
                           $('ul#root').append('<li id="node-'+ nodes[i].id +'"><input type="checkbox" name="">'+ nodes[i].name); 

                           // works on FF only
                          $('li#node-'+nodes[i].id +'').append('<ul id="' + nodes[i].id +'>'); 

                        }
                         else{
                           ...   
                           ... 
                        }
```

Comment: do you see the same problem here http://jsbin.com/elozi5/2/edit ?
this simplified example works on all browsers for me?

Comment: @Daveo - Yes the simplified example works on all browsers. However when i introduce the array node[] , it ceases to work.

the node[] has the following structure

node= [{id,name,parent_id,parent_name} , {..} , ...]

I have pasted my code in here http://jsbin.com/ifayu3/edit . Have a look, i am trying to create a quick and dirty checkbox hierarchy.

Thanks.

Comment: @Daveo - I can reproduce the bug here -- http://jsbin.com/ifayu3/4/edit just check in FF and Chrome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your HTML was invalid, and Chrome did not accept it. Firefox was more lenient in what it allowed. Whenever there are lots of quote openings and closings because of a dynamic value, it's better to use the object style element creation in jQuery rather than doing it all in a string. The problem is with this line:

```
$('li#node-'+nodes[i].id +'').append('<ul id="' + nodes[i].id +'>');
```

The output ul it produces is (notice the missing quote):

```
<ul id="1>
```

For creating complex selectors, it is much better to use string replacement:

```
var li = "li#node-{id}".replace("{id}", nodes[i].id);
```

To create elements with dynamic attributes, use objects to initialize:

```
var ul = $('<ul>', {
    id: nodes[i].id
});
```

The code below although a little verbose and maybe a little slow is hard to get wrong especially in a language like JavaScript where a missing quote can do havoc as we just witnessed.

```
var li = "li#node-{id}".replace("{id}", nodes[i].id);
var ul = $('<ul>', {
        id: nodes[i].id
    });
$(li).append(ul);
```

Comment: I understand that I can work with a reference but I am still not sure why Chrome would not work while FF clearly is ignoring any issues. I am more keen to understand the reason behind this.

Comment: @papdel - That's the spirit. Can you post a reproducible example on http://jsfiddle.net or something?

Comment: Added into the comment of the original question ( jsbin.com/ifayu3/edit )

Answer (score 1):

Consider creating the node as an element before inserting it, as then you have a reference to it and can skip the later lookup.  Something like:

```
$.getJSON("/data/all" , function(data){
                nodes = data;
                len = nodes.length;
for(i=0; i<len; i++){
                    if(i==0){
                       // works on FF && Chrome
                       var newNode = $('<li id="node-'+ nodes[i].id +'"><input type="checkbox" name="">'+ nodes[i].name);
                       $('ul#root').append(newNode); 

                       // works on FF only
                      newNode.append('<ul id="' + nodes[i].id +'>'); 

                    }
                     else{
                       ...   
                       ... 
                    }
```

Comment: The issue still persists across browsers. See comment above